# ng-repeat filter not working when range of the array is used

Tags: angularjs, loops, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

The array 'response' is what I get from my .php file

```
$http.get(encodedpage).success(function(response) {
      $scope.friends = response; 
}
```

It has a bunch of values and the filter is working correct

```
   <input type="search" ng-model="q" /> 
     <div class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="x in friends | filter:q as results">    
     {{x.name}} 
     </div>
```

When I want to just show a range of it, the filter is not working anymore.
Although everything is displayed and shown correctly.

```
$http.get(encodedpage).success(function(response) {
   for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            $scope.friends[i] = response[i]; 
        }
 }
```

I am giving up why.

here is a jsfiddle example

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/11646/

Comment: Possible to post your code in plnkr or jsfiddle? I tried to reproduce this scenario, it works good for me

Comment: hi, I just added a jsfiddle example, see here: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/11646/  the 'friendsreduced' are simply not filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the array declaration. Looks like you have declared it as an object and try to set elements into it.

```
$scope.friendsReduced = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $scope.friendsReduced[i] = $scope.friends[i];  
}
```

Jsfiddle is updated for your reference.

Comment: holy smokes, that really solved it, thank you so much.